# How to find a dynamic control (radio button) inside a placeholder in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, radio-button

I have gridview with 4 columns; in column 1 I added a place holder and other 3 columns are boundfields. In column 1 I'm adding radio buttons dynamically using html code by which I am able to select only one radio button. It's working well, but the problem is I am unable to find the radio button control when a button outside of the gridview is clicked.

Please help, I've been stuck on this problem for 4 days.

Thank you in advance.

I used the following code

.aspx File

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
            CellPadding="3" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" 
                onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
                >
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
        <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="FIRST NAME" DataField="FNAME"/>
        <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="LAST NAME" DataField="LNAME"/>
        <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="EMAIL" DataField="EMAIL"/>
        <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="AGE" DataField="AGE"/>
        </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Button  ID="btnSave" Text="Save" runat="server" onclick="btnSave_Click1"  />

    </form>
```

Code Behind file

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowIndex != -1 && e.Row.DataItem != null)
        {
            PlaceHolder holder = (PlaceHolder)e.Row.FindControl("ph");
            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
            rb.ID = "rbSelect";
            holder.Controls.Add(rb);
        }
    }



 protected void btnSave_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            PlaceHolder holder = (PlaceHolder)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("ph");
            RadioButton rbtn = holder.FindControl("rb") as RadioButton;
            if (rbtn.Checked == true)
            {
                Response.Write("<Script>alert('Radiocheck')</Script>");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you need to create dynamic `RadioButton`s at all. That makes all just more difficult without a benefit in this case(even if, a nested `Repeater` or `GridView` would be easier).

However,

you should not create dynamic controls in `RowDataBound` since that is triggered only if the `GridView` was databound. But since by default `ViewState` is enabled you wouldn't `DataBind` it on postbacks. Dynamic controls on the other hand must be recreated **on every postback**.

Therefore create them in `RowCreated` which is triggered on every postback. But note that you have (of course) no `DataItem` there since it is `null` at this stage(even if the grid will be databound).

So you should create cynamic controls in `RowCreated` but load them from `RowDataBound` where you can also access them (f.e. via `FindControl`).

But instead of adding html-control like `<input type='radio'` you should create and add a `RadioButton` with an id. Otherwise you won't be able to acess it later, so `holder.FindControl("rb")` will, be `null` since it's not a server-control.

Here's the complete modified code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        PlaceHolder holder = (PlaceHolder)e.Row.FindControl("ph");
        var rb = new RadioButton();
        rb.ID = "RbSample";
        rb.Text = "rb";
        holder.Controls.Add(rb);
    }
}

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        var rb = (RadioButton)e.Row.FindControl("RbSample");
        rb.Checked = row.Field<bool>("SampleActive");
    }
}


protected void btnSave_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        RadioButton rbtn = (RadioButton)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("RbSample");
        if (rbtn.Checked)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Radiocheck');", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't try to edit my answer if you want to comment but comment ;) Of course my code is just an exmaple, i don't know what datasource you use(f.e. if there's a field with the name `SampleActive`).

Comment: can you explain me what is the use of line "rb.Checked = row.Field<bool>("SampleActive");" im getting error in this line

Comment: @sree: If you mention _errors_ on SO, always say _what_ error you get.  `rb` might be null if you haven't used my code in `RowCreated` to create the `RadioButton` with the ID="RbSample".

Comment: Column 'Select' does not belong to table Table.
i want only radio button column without binding any data from database
if i remove above metioned line(rb.Checked = row.Field<bool>("SampleActive");) iam gettin error at "if(rbtn.Checked)"
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @sree: As i've mentioned in my first comment, that's just an example. I don't know your database schema(columns, types). I've assumed that it's a `bool` column(bit in sql-server) and the column-name "SampleActive".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23361/discussion-between-sree-and-tim-schmelter)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing FindControl with the "value" of the input, but not with the ASP.NET ID of the control, because it has none. Because it's not an ASP.NET control you cannot find it with FindControl.

I also don't know if you can loop through the Controls property of holder, because it's a plain html control. But you can try it out to put a breakpoint on the FindControl line and explore the Controls property of holder.