# Dynamic Gridview column not found on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview in which the columns are added dynamically. However upon postback, the columns are no longer there.

I'm aware that dynamically created items must be re-created upon postback, upon debugging, even though the creating column codes are executed successfully, but the gridview doesn not contain any column.

```
 protected void gvUsers_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {    //creating column 
            List<Module> listModule = getModules();
                foreach (Module m in listModule)
                {
                    TemplateField tfield = new TemplateField();
                    tfield.HeaderTemplate = new TickColumn(m.ModuleName);        
                    gvUsers.Columns.Add(tfield);
                }
        }


        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        { //Creation of checkboxes in the dynamic columns
             List<Module> listModule = getModules();
            int i = 3; // cell postioning
            foreach (Module m in listModule)
            {
                CheckBox cbActive = new CheckBox();
                cbActive.ID = m.ModuleID.ToString();
                e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(cbActive); //Error<- because the cell does not have the column
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Am i creating the column in the wrong event?

Comment: Shouldn't this be in databound event ?

Comment: The reason why it's placed in the RowCreateEvent because of [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517812/how-to-find-a-dynamic-controlradio-button-inside-a-placeholder-in-gridview) .      Check out tim's answer

Answer (score 0):

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {    //creating column 
        List<Module> listModule = getModules();
            foreach (Module m in listModule)
            {
                TemplateField tfield = new TemplateField();
                tfield.HeaderTemplate = new TickColumn(m.ModuleName);        
                tfield.Controls.Add(cbActive);
                CheckBox cbActive = new CheckBox();
                cbActive.ID = m.ModuleID.ToString();
                gvUsers.Columns.Add(tfield);
            }
    }
```

}

Try above code, I haven't compile the code but get the idea how to do it,

Comment: The checkbox creation is for the datarows, not for the header. The codes for creation is fine. I suspect its the event, for some reason it's refreshing the just created columns, making it null again on the postback.

Comment: try this link http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/330441/How-to-get-value-of-the-dynamically-created-contro